# Prepared statement : update only if field is set

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to update an element in the database using prepared statements.

The table has a lot of fields and only a few of them are submitted in the form

I found out that I can skip the empty fields by setting the value of the field to the field name itself.

```
UPDATE contacts set name=name, phone_number=phone_number .... WHERE id = 8;
```

So first I assume that all the fields are submitted;

```
$query = $db->prepare('UPDATE contacts set name = ?, phone_number = ? WHERE id = ?');
```

Then I bind each field to its value, depending on wheter its submitted or not

```
if (isset($name))
{
    $query->bindValue(1, $name);
}
else
{
    $query->bindValue(1, 'name');
}
if (isset($phone_number))
{
    $query->bindValue(2, $phone_number);
}
else
{
    $query->bindValue(2, 'phone_number');
}
$query->bindValue(3, $id);
$query->execute();
```

For some reason that I'm not aware of, nothing is updated even if the query works in phpmyadmin. However, it only works if all fields are submitted.

**UPDATE**

I have also tried using named parameters, but it does not seem to work :

```
$query = $db->prepare('UPDATE contacts set name = :name, phone_number = :phone_number WHERE id = :id');
if (isset($name))
{
    $query->bindValue(':name', $name);
}
else
{
    $query->bindValue(':name', 'name');
}
if (isset($phone_number))
{
    $query->bindValue(':phone_number', $phone_number);
}
else
{
    $query->bindValue(':phone_number', 'phone_number');
}
$query->bindValue(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
SQL: [77] UPDATE contacts set name = :name, phone_number = :phone_number WHERE id = :id
Params:  3
Key: Name: [5] :name
paramno=-1
name=[5] ":name"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [13] :phone_number
paramno=-1
name=[13] ":phone_number"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [3] :id
paramno=-1
name=[3] ":id"
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

Comment: Have you tried using named bindings instead of question marks?

Comment: @boyd what does it mean ?

Comment: Named parameters: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php. Is the output of `$query->debugDumpParams();` what you expect?  https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Comment: @boyd I tried it but it does not work either.  I also added the output of the query.

Comment: The question body contradicts with question title. So you don't want to update or want to update with some fixed value (the latter doesn't make sense in my eyes)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since this is my first exeperience with prepared statements in PHP, it took me a long time to realize that we cannot use string laterals directly in `bindValue`. So the solution was to store the value in a variable just like this :

```
$temp = 'name';
$query->bindValue(':name', $temp);
```

I hope that someone can explain this behaviour.

Comment: This answer is wrong. this is only true for bindparam but the OP is using bindvalue